# react native function always returns true

Tags: react-native

In my application, I want to disable an icon conditionally. Here is my code.

```
<View style={styles.controlsContainer}>
                    <WorkoutProgressControls 
                        videoPaused={this.state.videoPaused}
                        onPrevious={() => alert("PREVIOUS MOVEMENT")}
                        onPause={() => this._onPauseVideo()}
                        onNext={() => this.getNextMovement()}
                        disableNext={() => 1 === 1 ? false : true}
                    />
                </View>
```

When I set disableNext to true or false, it works properly. But when I tried to change it conditionally or using a function, it always gets disabled.

this is my component which set the disableNext prop.

```
 <DisableableIcon
                iconStyles={styles.icon}
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={Next}
                height={35}
                width={35}
                disabled={props.disableNext}
                onIconPressed={props.onNext}
            />
```

What is the issue here? Why does this work when I set disableNext to true and false, but returns true always when I try to set it conditionally?

Comment: Not a whole lot to go on but based on the upper code, `disableNext` expects a function. I would guess that `props.disableNext` is not a function, possibly the result of a function that is getting evaluated too early. Try `console.log(props.disableNext)` to see if you get something like `[function]` or an actual boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass a function as a prop, therefore to make it work either don't use a function or invoke it as a function in your component.

```
...
disableNext={() => 1 === 1 ? false : true}
...

...
disabled={props.disableNext()}
...
```

**OR**

```
...
disableNext={1 === 1 ? false : true}
...

...
disabled={props.disableNext}
...
```